# radio buttons are active on running the program

Tags: python

I have tried this code and facing with problem that all options of radiobuttons are coming to be selected intially i.e. all options are selected on running the program.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk

root=Tk()
a=Label(root,text='Name')
a.grid(row=0,column=0)
b=Entry(root)
b.grid(row=0,column=2)
a=Label(root)
a.grid(row=1)
a1=Label(root,text='Langauge')
a1.grid(row=2,column=0)

var=StringVar()
R1=Radiobutton(root, text="English", variable=var, value='English')
R1.grid(row=2,column=1)


R2=Radiobutton(root, text="Hindi", variable=var, value='Hindi')
R2.grid(row=2,column=2)


R3=Radiobutton(root, text="Punjabi", variable=var, value='Punjabi')
R3.grid(row=2,column=3)


R4=Radiobutton(root, text="Tamil", variable=var, value='Tamil')
R4.grid(row=2,column=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `var.set()` and pass it an argument of the value for the radiobutton you'd like to choose as default. For example:

```
var.set('English')
```

will set the "English" radiobutton as active.